# Opening Report with Filter from Array

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to open a report based on a company name from an array which I extracted from the database. When I try to apply the where condition in DoCmd.OpenReport it opens a text box instead with the name of the company I feed it. If I enter a company name into the text box it will filter for that input.

How can I get it to open with the where condition and no user input?

My eventual goal is to print the report once for each company to a PDF which is why I am using an array instead of user input or a fixed value.

*Example text box with the first company in the array Abbvie*
[image]

```
 Sub recordfilter()

      Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
      Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

       'point to the currently loaded database and pull company names
      myRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

      strSQL = "Select DISTINCT [CORP ID] FROM backlog"
      myRecordset.Open strSQL
      Dim i As Integer
      i = 0
      Do Until myRecordset.EOF
        i = i + 1
        myRecordset.MoveNext
      Loop
      Dim myarray()
      myRecordset.MoveFirst
      myarray = myRecordset.GetRows(, , "CORP ID")

      'Will be in loop with print command once completed
      DoCmd.OpenReport "SalesOrder_Query_Filter", acViewPreview, , "[CORP ID] = " & myarray(0, 0)


  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `[CORP ID]` field is string-valued, the criteria will need to be enclosed within either single or double quotes, e.g.:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "SalesOrder_Query_Filter", acViewPreview, , "[CORP ID] = '" & myarray(0, 0) & "'"
'                                                                         ^                     ^
'                                                                         |                     |
' Added single quotes ----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Or:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "SalesOrder_Query_Filter", acViewPreview, , "[CORP ID] = """ & myarray(0, 0) & """"
'                                                                         ^                      ^
'                                                                         |                      |
' Added double quotes ----------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Lee for your help! This was driving me nuts :)